# force asp:content or even div to stay on top while scrolling?

Tags: asp.net, css

I've got an asp:content tag that has say a div in it:

```
<asp:Content ID="btnContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ButtonContent" runat="server">
  <div id="dButtons" runat="server" visible="false">
    Some CONTENT
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

When I scroll down my page I no longer see this content panel (div).  Is there any way to force this to display even when I scroll down.  It should always be visibile.

Comment: Do you change `dButtons.visible` state to `true` in code behind? Actually `visible="false"` attribute makes `Some CONTENT` invisible. It may be even not rendered to browser

Answer (score 2):

In css, `position: fixed` will  make an element stay in place even if the page is being scrolled.

Comment: yea but that doesnt seem to work well with what i have, the buttons are off the screen (on the right side)...

Comment: `position:fixed` take the element off the page normal flow, you have to place your elements manually.